# Post to rails with json field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql, curl

I am trying to work with the new json field offered by Postgres and Rails. All I did so far was generating this scaffold and disabling the CSRF-tokens for testing reasons:

```
 rails generate scaffold Shipping name content:json
```

My goal is to send data like this:

```
 curl -vX POST https://myserver.com/shipping -d '{"shipping": { "name": "test", "content" : ["test","hello"] }}' --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

This does accept the name the name, but not the content. Is there a proper way to format the content or is there more to the problem?

Comment: _This does accept the name, but not the content_, can you add the logs when you make the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will filter out "scalar" parameters that aren't explicitly permitted. I'll bet you tried an ordinary string value and everything worked fine, but things don't work once you send either an array or object.

To get things working just update the original `shipping_params` method in your ShippingsController with this:

```
def shipping_params
  params.require(:shipping).permit(:name, content: {})
end
```

By the way, take a look at the [ActionController::Parameters API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit). I'm sure you'll eventually add more attributes to your model and will need to add keys for those too.

*For what it's worth: you may encounter the similar `permit!` method in the referenced documentation. Just be careful if you a) use a model's attributes to make any authorization decisions, and b) allow people you don't trust to use your API. The last thing you'd want to do is let someone set something like an `is_admin` column to true on a user-like model.*

Comment: Thank you! My mind wandered back to Rails 3 times I guess when you didn't have to care about permit. I can not accept json arrays atm, but {"data" => ["test","ahoy"]} works. That's good enough for me right now :)